# Retrieving low confidence score when adding my own classifier for MobileNetV2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following code adding the classifier, I retrieve a low confidence score.

```
import keras
from keras import layers,Model
from keras.layers import Input,GlobalAveragePooling2D,Flatten,Dense
MobileNetV2_model= keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=None, alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
x= MobileNetV2_model.output
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
final_output=Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model =keras.Model(inputs=MobileNetV2.input, outputs = final_output)
for layer in MobileNetV2.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='BinaryCrossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],loss_weights=0.1)
#model.summary()
```

I trained the model using below code on 2048 images for two categories cat and dog

```
 history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Comment: What do you mean "drops the accuracy"?

Comment: By drop in accuracy I mean low confidence threshold

Comment: That makes no sense and is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving binary classification problems, if you are using sigmoid as your activation function, your dense layer should have 1 neuron instead of 2 neurons. If you use softmax, then your dense layer should have 2 neurons. You should choose between two of them and change the amount of output neuron accordingly. You can learn more about this in [here](https://www.quora.com/For-a-classification-problem-two-classes-is-it-better-to-use-two-outputs-with-softmax-or-one-output-with-binary-cross-entropy).

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply it was a typo mistake

Comment: This will change your confidence threshold so that you should always have one high-confidence class (or two close-in-confidence). The solution to your initial problem is as @Tsuki described above. Now any remaining errors will be pertaining to your data or model specifically, and is better served as a new question (with a bit more info, please).